# python link list remove at first

Tags: python, linked-list

Ok, so I was playing around with link list . I really couldn't figure it out why it doesn't work. Can someone explain why?

Don't bother about the insert part, let's see the removeFirst (more simple).

```py
class Node():
    def __init__(self, data = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class Link():
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def insertFirst(self, data_n):
        node = Node(data_n)
        head = self
        node.next = head.head
        head.head = node

    def display(self):
        head = self.head
        while head != None:
            print(head.data, end = '->')
            head = head.next
        print()

    def removeFirst(self):
        head = self.head
        head = head.next
```

The below code dosen't work.

```py
def removeFirst(self):
    head = self.head
    head = head.next
```

But, this one works.

```py
def removeFirst(self):
    #head = self.head
    self.head = self.head.next
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Does "I found out this" mean you did not write this?

Comment: Snippet 1 overwrites the local variable `head`, not the member variable `self.head`.

Comment: @Mugunth.. ooty ya?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first function just assigns the value of `self.head` and then the value of `head.next` to `head`

```
def removeFirst(self):
    head = self.head
    head = head.next
```

Which is sort of equivalent to

```
self.head = 1
head.next = 2
x = 1
x = 2
```

Which doesn't do anything

The second function actually takes the element next to head and makes it the new head, and the old head is garbage collected!

```
def removeFirst(self):
    #head = self.head
    self.head = self.head.next
```

So if earlier the list was

```
self.head   self.head.next
 1 -----------> 2
```

The list changes to

```
self.head
2
```

Comment: Thanks for the accept @mugunth! Have a great day :)

Answer (score 1):

```
def removeFirst(self):
    head = self.head
    head = head.next
```

You create a local variable, `head`, that takes the value of `self.head`, and then the value of `head.next`.
That's all these two lines do.

```
def removeFirst(self):
    self.head = self.head.next
```

You bind the value of `self.head.next` into the `head` attribute of `self`. So now, `self.head` is equal to `self.head.next`.

---

It looks like your confusion comes from the fact that in other common object oriented languages, the member scope is the whole class, like if you had a `head` member in a `Link` class in C# or Java, then simply `head` in any instance method would be a direct reference to `this.head`.

Well, in Python, things don't work like that, and this is why we pass `self` to instance methods.
If you want to act on the instance's members, you have to prefix them by `self.`.

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
head = self.head
head = head.next
```

first creates a new reference to the object currently referenced by `self.head` (let's call it object `A`). Then the `head` is reassigned to point to `A.next`. The outcome of this is that `self.next` is completely unaffected and still points to `A`. Unlike the alternative construction you offered.